# Silverlight 3 and IMultiValueConverter

Tags: c#, data-binding, silverlight-3.0, c#-3.0

As you may know, Silverlight 3 doesn't support IMultiValueConverter and... I badly need it. A Web Service proxy which defines a class structure that I need to display in my UI. The object definition class has a few array property such as string[], int[], etc. When I bind these property to a TextBlock, the Text property of the TextBlock becomes System.String[] or System.Int[]. Instead, I would like to see a list strings or numbers separated by a comma.

I thought about using a IMultiValueConverter but Silverlight 3 doesn't support it. How do I work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of `IMultiValueConverter` is to implement converters that support *multiple bindings* (i.e. `MultiBinding` objects). In your case, this doesn't actually seem to be what you need.

If you want to convert an array (`string[]` for example) into a text value, then simply define a normal `IValueConverter` that does that. Don't let the fact that an array contains *multiple values* confuse you.

Here's an example converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string[]), typeof(string))] 
public class StringArrayConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Join(", ", (string[])value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the use of a Multivalue Converter in your scenario. You can create a IValueConverter which takes Array and return you the string comma separated

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ArrayProperty,Converter={StaticResource stringArrayToString}}" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you still want to have MultiBinding and IMultiValueConverter, you can you [this one by Colin Eberhardt](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/wpf/2009/06/silverlight-multibindings-how-to-attached-mutiple-bindings-to-a-single-property/). Works really fine.