# data binding converter for lat/long (multiple parameters)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am using Web Services to receive a list of objects which I have then directly data bound to pushpins. However the object has coordinates as a latitude and longitude (so separate properties). Whilst I can obviously add a Geocoordinate Location property to the auto-generated code I would rather not (as it is auto-generated)

So when data binding to the pushpin it wants a location but I don't know how you can bind it to two separate items. So I thought maybe a converter could take the 2 items and return a location but I don't think a converter can take 2 values like this?

MultiBinding looked like the solution but doesn't seem to exist in Silverlight unfortunately so looks like a different approach is necessary

So, is there a way to bind like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an temporary object that stores the two values as properties and pass this to the converter. Multibinding is not supported, but there are a couple ways around that. This is one way

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand what you mean by this. As in, how can I create a temporary object within the XAML code. Is that possible?

Comment: You could create a wrapper class, called Info which exposes Long and Lat properties. You could set these properties in Xaml and then pass the Info class as a parameter. There are also plenty of examples online. Here is one: http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2009/07/imultivalueconverter-with-silverlight.html and here is another one that uses a delimited string (which i won't recommend!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156177/silverlight-3-and-imultivalueconverter